# conditions in logback configuration

Tags: logback, janino

I'm trying to remove redundant logback config files by using janino's conditional processing.

Below is the conditional logic which I had added

```
<root level="INFO">     
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
    <!-- use console appender on windows, email appender on linux -->
    <if condition='property("os.name").contains("win")'>
        <then>
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </then>
        <else>
            <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
        </else>
    </if>       
</root>
```

but this throws the below errors

```
12:30:34,877 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@90:55 - no applicable action for [if], current pattern is [[configuration][root][if]]
12:30:34,877 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@91:10 - no applicable action for [then], current pattern is [[configuration][root][if][then]]
12:30:34,877 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@92:35 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current pattern is [[configuration][root][if][then][appender-ref]]
12:30:34,877 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@94:10 - no applicable action for [else], current pattern is [[configuration][root][if][else]]
12:30:34,877 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@95:35 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current pattern is [[configuration][root][if][else][appender-ref]]
```

The configuration works fine if I remove the conditional logic and use something like

```
<root level="INFO">     
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />        
</root>
```

How can I configure this correctly in such a way that the CONSOLE appender is used only on Windows and the EMAIL appender everywhere else?

Comment: what is the logback library version you use?

Comment: version 0.9.17 of logback and version 1.5.8 of slf4j

Comment: Can you try the latest version? I used the latest version and the above conditional statements work perfectly fine

Comment: thanks. It works with newer versions of logback :-)

Comment: @AndyDufresne - can you answer this question with the same comment so that I can mark it answered?

Comment: use latest version and then use this condition:   'property("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the latest version? I used the latest version and the above conditional statements work perfectly fine

Comment: even for me it worked with using latest version of logback